# Asp.net core Group by without duplicating field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core, lambda

I have a table called "DeliveryFinance" which contains Delivery finance related datas. Here I need to get the top ten drivers list based on the order's he/she delivered, the datas that need to get is

1. DriverId
2. OrderNo -- The last delivered order number of the driver --
3. Count

To achieve this, I grouped it by DriverId and got the count. But i am not able to get the last OrderNo of the drivers

My DeliverFiance Table

```
| DriverId| OrderNo
|------------------
| 123123  | KSADJK| 
| 345534  | LJJSAS|
| 123123  | VXZXCZ|
| 123123  | REQWFA|
| 565534  | MCJSL1|
| 345534  | ASDCA3|
```

Expected Result

```
| DriverId| OrderNo | Count |
|----------------------------
| 123123  | REQWFA  |      3|
| 345534  | ASDCA3  |      2|
| 565534  | MCJSL1  |      1|
```

Here is my code, Can someone help me to get the last order number

```
var query = context.DeliveryFinances.AsQueryable();
var grouped = await query.GroupBy(x => new { DriverId = x.DriverId} )
                                     .Select(x => new { DriverId = x.Key.DriverId, Count = x.Count()})
                                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                                     .Take(10)
                                     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Is your OrderId an incrementing integer, the highest of which is therefore the last (=most recent) order ID?

Comment: No my order Id is some randomly generated string.  For example  "IKH3JE4"

Comment: So what is used to detect "most recent"ness of it?

Comment: Is LastOrderNo a column in eg the driver table?

Comment: OrderNo is the column name of the table. i need to get the last OrderNo of the selected drivers

Comment: and the selected driver has the most count?

Comment: What makes a given order number the "last" one?

Comment: What version of EF core are you using?

Comment: I am using .Net 5

Comment: hey sory, So basically i consider  the "last" order number is, the last entry's order number of the driver id in the table

Comment: You still aren't answering the question. You've said an OrderNumber has no inherent sequence so it cannot, of itself, support a notion of "last". Show example table data, one row that IS "the last" row and one row that IS NOT "the last" row. Say clearly and explicitly *why* the last row is the last one

Comment: You get the list of the top ten drivers first, and then get your last order. Do you just get the top 10 and take the last one every time? Do I need to get the last order based on time?